# including a google GWT jar - doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I'm trying to follow this beginner tutorial about Google Charts: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted

I already have an issue at the beginning where they say:

> Since we are working with an additional library, add the library
>   gwt-visualization.jar to the Java classpath. Then, add the module
>   com.google.gwt.visualization.Visualization to your module.

According to my research I have to copy **gwt-visualization.jar** to **war/WEB-INF/lib**

After I did that, I still have this error message:

[image]

I've also added the module into the XML file.

Could anybody give me a hint what I am missing?

Info:
Eclipse 4.2 Juno
Mac OS X Lion

Comment: It is evident you have not yet tried programming in Java before attempting GWT. I believe strongly you should abandon your current pursuit but first try programming in Java by itself - and using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yellow wiggly lines aren't errors but warnings, i.e. they don't usually prevent your code from running but hint at things that might not be right.

In your case, the two `import` statements are referencing the [deprecated class `c.g.g.v.c.visualizations.PieChart`](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/visualization/1.1/com/google/gwt/visualization/client/visualizations/PieChart.html%60). According to the javadoc of the deprecated `PieChart` class, you should be using [`c.g.g.v.c.visualizations.corechart.PieChart`](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/visualization/1.1/com/google/gwt/visualization/client/visualizations/corechart/PieChart.html) instead (note the extra `corechart` package).

It might just work without changing the class name --- deprecated classes aren't somehow broken, they just will go away in future versions of a library and you're encouraged to replace them with non-deprecated code. So given that this is mainly tutorial code for learnign GWT, just try if it works with the deprecated classes first.

Note: I abbreviated package names above, don't use them verbatim but use `com.google.gwt.visualization.client`.